# How to find a vector using angle?

Tags: vector

In 3 dimensional space i have an ine object between x and y axis.If the angle between x and y axis given,how  can we find a vector value(i,j,k) ?please  help to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this website might not be the right place for this question... Try here maybe: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The x and y axis are in the same plane so you would actually need the z axis angle as well to do this. (at least a combination of x, y and z (not just x and y)).

Comment: Yes,the z axis angle alse given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what X and Y axis are. Supposing this usual axis naming:

[image: X-Y-Z]

X and Y axis angle do not define the vector in 3D space (which I guess is what you want since you want a 3-component vector) because angle with X actually is the same than angle with Y (they're related).

You should explain what angles you have. This problem only has solution if the two angles are independent (or the space is 2D).

Comment: The 3 angles between the objects to x,y,z axis are given.

Comment: Then if we take angles with X axis as alpha, with Y axis as beta and with Z as gamma, you got that (V being your vector module): i = V * cos(alpha); j = V * sin(alpha) [or j = V * cos(beta)]; z = V * cos(gamma) for V = (i,j,k).